# How to use the clear screen/cls functionality in the MySQL Command line client?

Tags: mysql-cli

So I am using the MySQL 5.7 Command line client on a Windows OS here and to remove the clutter from screen I want to use the clear screen/cls functionality even after seeing some tutorials on the internet they are not working for me can anybody tell how can I do so ?

these are some of the methods that i tried but did not work :
method 1: Ctrl + L , when I tried this only a exponent symbol followed by a capital L appeared on my command line

method 2: I also tried using 'system cls' and 'system clear' but nothing happened the cursor just shifted to the next line after pressing enter and if i added semicolon to their ends then the system just responded with invalid syntax